# Syntax issue while sending data using OneSignal sendTags in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, onesignal

I am facing build issue in this line. It's taking lot of time to buid.

```
   strJsonBody = "{"
        +   "\"app_id\": " + GUARD_APP_ID + ","
                                    +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
        +   "\"include_player_ids\": [" + playerId + "],"
        +   "\"data\": {\"name\": \"" + user_name + "\", \"email\": \"" + user_email + "\", \"phone\": \"" + user_phone + "\", \"uniqueCode\": \"" + user_uniqueCode + "\", \"uid\": \"" + user_uid + "\", \"type\": \"SOS\"},"
        +   "\"headings\": {\"en\": \"Resident SOS\"},"
        +   "\"ios_group\": \"sos\","
        +   "\"ios_sound\": \"sos\","
        +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"" + user_name + " signalled SOS\"}"
        + "}";
```

Is there any other way to do this and when i am passing this strJsonBody in sendtags then it is giving error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]!'".

```
   OneSignal.sendTags(strJsonBody as Any, onSuccess: { (result) in
        print("success!")
    }) { (error) in
        print("Error sending tags - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a JSON string, when the API is expecting a JSON-compatible dictionary. This should compile:

```
let tags = [
    "app_id": GUARD_APP_ID,
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "include_player_ids": [playerId],
    "data": [
        "name": user_name,
        "email": user_email,
        "phone": user_phone,
        "uniqueCode": user_uniqueCode,
        "uid": user_uid,
        "type": "SOS" ],
    "headings": [ "en": "Resident SOS" ],
    "ios_group": "sos",
    "ios_sound": "sos",
    "contents": ["en": "\(user_name) signalled SOS"],
]
OneSignal.sendTags(tags, onSuccess: { (result) in
    print("success!")
}) { (error) in
    print("Error sending tags - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

However, it doesn't look like those are tags you're sending. It ***looks*** like you're trying to directly send a push notification from your app. I'm not sure the OneSignal API supports that.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to send push notification from my app.

Comment: You want the `postNotification` method: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--postnotification-

Comment: Dave i am trying to send the notification and also getting the success in response but i am not reciving the notifciation.

Comment: Please post another question.

Comment: Dave please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089778/one-signal-notification-issue-in-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment73263284_43089778

Answer (score 1):

```
let payload = [
    "app_id": GUARD_APP_ID,
    "include_player_ids": [playerId],
    "data": [
        "name": user_name,
        "email": user_email,
        "phone": user_phone,
        "uniqueCode": user_uniqueCode,
        "uid": user_uid,
        "type": "SOS" ],
    "headings": [ "en": "Resident SOS" ],
    "ios_sound": "sos",
    "contents": ["en": "\(user_name) signalled SOS"],
]
OneSignal.postNotification(payload, onSuccess: { (result) in
    print("success!")
}) { (error) in
    print("Error posting notification - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**Remove:**

```
"included_segments": ["All"], // Removed for security reasons
"ios_group": "sos", // Not an option
```

sendTags is for marking users for segmentation later. You would nee to use postNotification to send a notification in real time.